# How can I add an accepted friend to a User schema?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I have two schemas: `User` and `FriendRequest`. I'm working on a Facebook clone so I have profile pages with usernames as URL paths. When you visit someones page, you click a button that says *Send Friend Request* to send the friend request. There's also a `requests` page that allows the user to either accept or deny a friend request. I have that all set up and working just fine. However, one thing I'm having trouble figuring out is adding two users as `friends` in the `User` schema. I have everything worked out perfectly inside the `FriendRequest` schema but inside the `User` schema, the friends value isn't being updated and no one is actually shown as friends. One of the reasons I need both users to show up in each others `friends` object is so I can have a page that shows a list of all your friends EXAMPLE: `/:username/friends`.

User Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  password: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  profilePictureURL: String,
  friends: [ // This is where I'm having trouble. It's showing as empty for everyone.
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
});
```

FriendRequest Schema

```
const friendRequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  receiver: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["pending", "accepted", "rejected"],
    default: "pending",
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

GET route for friend requests

```
router.get("/requests", async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.user;
  const id = req.user.id;

  const requests = await FriendRequest.find({
    toUser: user._id,
    status: "pending",
  })
    .populate("sender")
    .populate("receiver");

  res.render("requests", { requests, id });
});
```

POST route to handle the friend request submission

```
router.post("/friend-requests", (req, res) => {
  const { sender, receiver } = req.body;

  // Create a new FriendRequest instance
  const newRequest = new FriendRequest({
    sender,
    receiver,
  });

  // Save the friend request to the database
  newRequest
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      // Redirect to a success page or send a response indicating success
      res.status(204).send();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the error appropriately
      res.status(500).send("Error sending friend request");
    });
});
```

ACCEPT or REJECT the friend request

```
router.post("/requests/:id/accept", async (req, res) => {
  const request = await FriendRequest.findById(req.params.id);
  request.status = "accepted";
  await request.save();
  res.redirect("/requests");
});

router.post("/requests/:id/reject", async (req, res) => {
  const request = await FriendRequest.findById(req.params.id);
  request.status = "rejected";
  await request.save();
  res.redirect("/requests");
});
```